# Choice of tense after Present Perfect

Tags: grammar

I have lost my wallet.  I have looked in the bedroom but it ISN'T THERE or IT WASN'T THERE? Which is correct?

Comment: Both versions are fine. Because you've used *Present Perfect* in the initial context, there's a strong implication that ***the wallet is still lost***. If your context had been *Simple Past*, as ***I lost my wallet. I looked in the bedroom but...***, you might be talking about when you lost your wallet yesterday (or last year), in which case you ***wouldn't*** use Present Tense for *...it **isn't** there*. But with the example as presented, it's just a stylistic choice.

Answer (score 1):

Because you said "I **have** looked", you should say that it *isn't* there.

- I **have looked** and it **isn't** there.
- I looked and it **wasn't** there

Saying "I have looked" is the present perfect, so you can say that it isn't (present) there. "I looked" is simple past.

Comment: I agree with this response for American English.  The present perfect has a different range of use for British and American English, however, so I don't know what is acceptable for British English.  (I don't know about other varieties off hand.)  In American English, the present perfect describes the current moment and so is not very compatible with a linked clause using past reference.  The second option in the answer is the default if the looking led into the present statement.  The first option is better when other events have intervened between the looking and the statement.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use 'It isn't there'.

I have lost my wallet.- present perfect tense

-(simple present tense) 'Where is your wallet?'
-(present perfect tense) 'I have lost it.'

I have lost my wallet. (I haven't got it now)

The present perfect talks about the past and the present -

(present perfect)I have looked. (simple present) **It isn't there**.

The simple past tense talks about the past -

(simple past) I looked.  (simple past) It wasn't there.